# Does Mahabrahma create the lives of those that join him in a new world?

Tags: god, western-philosophy, brahma, worldly

Does Mahabrahma create the lives of those that join him in a new world? From wikipedia

> During the Vivartakalpa, a deity from Abhassara plane is reborned in
> the Mahabrahma plane, as many living beings forget about their past
> life, this too happens with the Mahabrahma, and being unaware of the
> above planes of existence, he felt alone. He longs for the presence of
> others. After some times many other deities from the above planes were
> also reborn in those brahma planes, as his ministers and
> companions.[7] Seeing this happens, he falsely believes himself to be
> their creator and other deities believed the same. This belief, state
> the Buddhist texts, is then shared by other deities. Eventually,
> however one of the deity dies and is reborn as human, practicing
> meditation,he got the power to remember his previous life.[6] He
> teaches what he remembers from his previous life in lower heaven, that
> Mahabrahma is the Creator. It is this that leads to the human belief
> in Creator, according to the Pali Canon.

So, mahabrahamd does not create their sentience (which existed prior to this world cycle): but does he create their presence with him or their life?

I'm asking because I'm unsure whether there is truly no omnipotence in Buddism.

Answer (score 1):

[One of the many wrong views in DN1](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/dn/dn.01.0.than_en.html#dn1sec5) will explain it, good householder.

There are Brahmas, good householder, like here the 'creater' of this BSE-realm, where good householder now dwells. Like parents, he, good householder, would not have taken birth here, as desired, if there are no Gods at first place, giving the possibilities.

And even this Sasana has it's "[creator-god](https://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/iti/iti.4.100-112.than_en.html)":

> This was said by the Blessed One, said by the Arahant, so I have heard: "I am a brahman, responsive to requests, open-handed, bearing my last body, an unsurpassed doctor & surgeon. You are my children, my sons, born from my mouth, born of the Dhamma, created by the Dhamma, heirs to the Dhamma, not heirs in material things....

...yet, less are willing to become his child, seeing more benefit in material things.

Got the 'point'?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the text carefully, the First Brahma to be born in the plane thought that all other Brahma's who were born after him, was his creation. It was his belief. Since the First Born Brahma was already present when the others were born, those who were born later, also believed that the First Brahma was their creator. Similar to the humans, when a Brahma was born, the memory of previous life were forgotten.
One of the Brahma died and was born as a human and, as a human he practiced meditation and learned the way to access the memories of previous lives. Usually, those who gain this ability gain it for viewing a limited number of previous lifetimes (i.e. - 1,3,7). So, when the, now-human Brahma viewed his past lives he sees his previous life as a Brahma and learns what he belied as a Brahma (That the First Brahma created him), and taught it to others. Its like me saying that I'm your dad. But will that belief make me your dad? It won't, isn't it?

Maha Brahma did not create anything. The only thing he created was his own perception of his own-world, just like we all do. We perceive the outside and build our own version of the world, and Maha Brahma did the same. And when he did, he was mistaken that he was the creator, and others believed the same when they themselves built their own version of their own-world. After all, everyone lives in their own private version of the world (Moha). And in it, they interpret the existence of themselves and others, there is no creation. Its just interpretation of an input.